# How to differentiate between Firefox tabs?

Tags: javascript, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox4

I am currently developing a Firefox extension, and I need the ability to be able to differentiate between each open tab.

The idea is to be able to associate outgoing HTTP requests with its origin tab. For each '**on-modify-request**' event that is observed, for example, I would know that it came from tab #2, or tab #3.

This would have to be good enough to differentiate between multiple instances of the same website. Enumerating through all open tabs will not work if I have three 'www.google.com' tabs open for example.

As far as I know, tabbrowser objects in Mozilla do not have any unique identifiers or properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http-on-modify-request` gives you the actual request object. From there you need to get the associated window, the way to go is [nsILoadContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Updating_extensions_for_Firefox_3.5#Getting_a_load_context_from_a_request) here. I use this code:

```
function getRequestWindow(request)
{
  try
  {
    if (request.notificationCallbacks)
      return request.notificationCallbacks
                    .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsILoadContext)
                    .associatedWindow;
  } catch(e) {}

  try
  {
    if (request.loadGroup && request.loadGroup.notificationCallbacks)
      return request.loadGroup.notificationCallbacks
                              .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsILoadContext)
                              .associatedWindow;
  } catch(e) {}

  return null;
}
```

That's a content window (and probably even a frame). So you have to find the corresponding tab - use [gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-getBrowserForDocument). Like this:

```
var wnd = getRequestWindow(request);
var browser = (wnd ? gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(wnd.top.document) : null);
```

Now you have the `<browser>` element that the request belongs to - if any. Because the request might also originate from the Firefox UI or a different browser window. You can set your own expando property on that element to get a tab identifier (choose a unique name to avoid conflicts with other extensions). Something like this:

```
if (!("_myExtensionTabId" in browser))
    browser._myExtensionTabId = ++maxTabId;
var tabId = browser._myExtensionTabId;
```

Here `maxTabId` would be a global variable that's initially zero. And "myExtension" would be ideally replaced by something unique to your extension (e.g. its name).

Comment: While this will get me the <browser> object associated for each request, is there a way to uniquely identify the <browser> element from the others that are open? I'm trying to store this relation into a database (i.e. request xyz came from <browser> element X), which will cause me to run into problems if I can't use unique identifiers. Or am I misunderstanding your code snippet?

Comment: You understand the code snippet correctly but I probably don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Objects unfortunately don't have unique identifiers that you could use in a hash table. So the usual approach is expando properties - you actually store all the required data in `browser._myExtensionRequests` (use a unique property name to avoid conflicts with other extensions). So when you need data for a particular tab you know where to find it - and you don't keep data around for tabs that no longer exist. Does that help?

Comment: Yes - for my uses it seems this won't be possible then. I basically wanted a way to group http requests together by their origin <browser> element in the database. This is easy if I just group by the URL that made these requests, but differentiating between instances of <browser> elements with identical URLs makes this trickier...

Comment: P.S. If you elaborate on this point in your answer I'd be happy to accept it :).

Comment: You could use `gBrowser.getBrowserIndexForDocument()` instead of `gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument()` to get a "tab identifier" but that index can change as tabs are added/removed/reordered. On the other hand, nobody stops you from using expando properties to create a tab identifier of your own. I edited my answer to describe that approach.